# Set up a working copy under both Git and Svn version control

Tags: git, svn, version-control

For reasons I will not go into explaining (unless required) I have two repos, a subversion and a git one, where my project (identical copies of it) is located. I need to keep it this way, if possible.

Hence, what I would like to accomplish in order to maintain consistency between the two, is to set up a directory on my machine where I can `svn checkout` the project, work on it, and then push the changes to *both* the svn and the git repos.

I have read something about the `git svn` command but from what I gathered it only serves as a way to use git *locally* and then push (rather, `dcommit`) your work to the svn repo.
Nonetheless, I naively tried issuing: `git svn init <url to svn repo> -s --username <uid> test` (did not prompt for pwd, did not checkout working copy, only created folder .git inside folder test) followed by: `git svn clone <url to git repo> test` and it returned:

```
svn-remote.svn.url already set: <url to svn repo>
wanted to set to: <url to git repo>
```

However, my hopes are high thanks to this post here on SO: [How to deal with Git-svn when have to use both Git and Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116546/how-to-deal-with-git-svn-when-have-to-use-both-git-and-subversion) where it looks like the OP's workflow consists of both `git svn dcommit` and `git push` commands.
If there is a way to accomplish what I wish, could someone please instruct me step by step on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. As an added bonus of this peculiar configuration, I would like to be able to svn:ignore a certain folder of my project but have it pushed on the git repo (i.e. the img/local folder must not be committed to svn since there is a rule saying it should be ignored, but there is no such entry in the .gitignore file, so I assume that files added to it will be pushed to the git repo, but not to the svn one, right?)

Comment: Update: I have just stumbled upon [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162949/manage-source-under-git-and-svn-simultanously-does-it-make-sense) where it looks like what I want to accomplish is in fact possible, however it does not go into detail as to how I can boostrap this set up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [post you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162977/6309) would require as simple a bootstrap as:

- moving your `.git` folder in the root directory of your svn local workspace
- examine the output of a `git status`, and see if you need to add anything to your `.gitignore`.

The other option would be to use a dedicated tool, specialized in the round-trip synchronization of svn-git repos, like **[SubGit](http://subgit.com/)** (presented on [GitMinutes episode 22](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/09/gitminutes-22-alexander-kitaev-about.html)).
But then, the working spaces (one for git, one for svn) would still be separate.